# How can I create a persisted state hook that uses cookies and server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to setup a hook that stores the selected state on cookies and I wan't it to be able to access cookies via server side rendering. Problem is that the only way I can think of accessing cookies from server side is via the getServerSideProps method exported from pages, and I don't have this method available on this hook. Here is the code:

```js
// src/hooks/persistedState.tsx
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

type Response<T> = [T, Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>];

export default function usePersistedState<T = any>(key: string, initialState: T): Response<T> {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies([key]);

  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(() => {
    if (cookies[key]) return cookies[key];

    return initialState;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setCookie(key, state);
  }, [key, setCookie, state]);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

When this hook is executed on the server, "cookies[key]" will always be null even if there is a cookie set. This means that server side rendering will get the "initialState", whilst client side rendering the cookie is present. This leads to inconsistencies when rendering the page.

[Here](https://clube-73-8nz6o6l3w-brunobmello25.vercel.app/timer) is a working example. Try selecting dark theme and then reloading the page.

Here is my _app.tsx

```js
// src/pages/_app.tsx
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from 'next-auth/client';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';

import DialogContainer from '../components/shared/DialogContainer';
import { ToastsContainer } from '../components/shared/ToastsContainer';

import { ThemeContextProvider, useTheme } from '../hooks/theme';
import { DialogContextProvider } from '../hooks/dialog';
import { NormalTimerContextProvider } from '../hooks/timer/normal';
import { ToastContextProvider, useToast } from '../hooks/toast';
import { SoundContextProvider } from '../hooks/sound';

import GlobalStyle from '../styles/global';

const AppWithProviders: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const { messages } = useToast();

  return (
    <AuthProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <CookiesProvider>
        <SoundContextProvider>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <DialogContextProvider>
              <NormalTimerContextProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                <GlobalStyle />
                <DialogContainer />
                <ToastsContainer messages={messages} />
              </NormalTimerContextProvider>
            </DialogContextProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </SoundContextProvider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => (
  <ThemeContextProvider>
    <ToastContextProvider>
      <AppWithProviders {...props} />
    </ToastContextProvider>
  </ThemeContextProvider>
);

export default MyApp;
```

And here is where I'm trying to access this hook:

```js
// src/hooks/theme.tsx

import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components';
import { dark, light } from '../styles/themes';
import usePersistedState from './persistedState';

export type Theme = 'dark' | 'light';

interface ThemeContextProps {
  theme: DefaultTheme;
  toggleTheme: () => void;
  currentTheme: Theme;
}

const ThemeContext = createContext({} as ThemeContextProps);

export const ThemeContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [storedTheme, setStoredTheme] = usePersistedState<Theme>('theme', 'light');
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<DefaultTheme>(storedTheme === 'light' ? light : dark);

  const toggleTheme = useCallback(() => {
    if (storedTheme === 'dark') {
      setTheme(light);
      setStoredTheme('light');
    } else {
      setTheme(dark);
      setStoredTheme('dark');
    }
  }, [setStoredTheme, storedTheme]);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme,
        toggleTheme,
        currentTheme: storedTheme,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => {
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);

  if (!themeContext) {
    throw new Error('useTheme must be used within a ThemeContext.Provider');
  }

  return themeContext;
};
```

Comment: You have access to the cookies in `getServerSideProps` to extract the theme value, which you could then pass down to the page's props (and to `ThemeContextProvider`) and use as `usePersistedState`'s initial value.

Comment: yes but that means I'd have to implement the same logic on every page that uses this hook, which doesn't sound ideal to me.